# Defining a struct as a class attribute

Tags: python, django

I'm defining a class in a Django project and I want a class to have a specific structure.

Versions used:
Django2.2.3
python3.7

I thought about defining the struct as a class and then adding it as an attribute for the main class. But then I am afraid it will create a DB.

This is what I tried:

```py
from django.db import models


class Host(models.Model):
    id_host = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    [... more attributes here ...]

class Apartment(models.Model):
    _id = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    host = Host()
    [... more attributes here ...]
```

Any idea on how to do this correctly?

EDIT:
The question is:
How do I code it so that I can define the Host struct and not create a Host DB table while being able to add Host as an Apartment attribute and DO create an Apartment DB?

Comment: advice: separate visually attributes that are db columns (`_id` and other `Field`s) and attributes that are just plain python class attributes (host).

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly fine to add custom attributes to your Django model class. It won't create an additional field in your DB. Note that the fields that will be created in your database are managed by migrations anyway. That way you can check which fields will be created when adding or removing attributes from your model class.

Comment: Cool, thanks! But how does the migration command know which classes transform into tables?

Comment: It only takes descendants of `models.Field` as attributes that map to a database column. `CharField`, `ForeignKey` and any custom field you create all need to subclass `Field`. Also, your question is 'which classes transform into tables', that's the case for every `models.Model` subclass that isn't abstract or proxy. So `Host` and `Apartment` will be mapped to a table in your DB.

Comment: Okay, so I my question remains unanswered, I guess. How do I code it so that I can define the Host struct and not create a Host DB table while being able to add Host as an Apartment attribute and DO create an Apartment DB? I hope it is understandable